# Add section and control to WordPress Customizer

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to learn how to add new sections and control to WordPress Customizer. I watched a video about how to do it and copied exactly the author's code(adding color picker) but it did not work for me. 
So, I have two files in the root of my child theme: customizer.php and functions.php.

In functions.php I require the customizer.php as follows:

```
function my_enqueue_assets() {
        require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/customizer.php';}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_assets' );
```

And in customizer.php I have the following code:

```
function wcmcr_add_colour_picker( $wp_customize ) {
        $wp_customize->add_setting(
            'wcmcr_title_colour',
            array(
                'default'   => '#000',
                'capability'    => 'manage_options',
                'transport'     => 'postMessage',
                'priority'  => 10
                )
            );
        $wp_customize->add_section(
            'wcmcr_section_colour',
            array(
                'title'     => 'Colour Options',
                'description'   => 'Colour Options for WCMCR',
                'capability'    => 'manage_options',
                'priority'  => '10',
                'panel'     => 'wcmcr_panel'
                )
            );
        $wp_customize->add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'wcmcr_title_colour',
                array(
                    'lable'     => 'Title Color',
                    'section'   => 'wcmcr_section_colour',
                    'settings'  => 'wcmcr_title_colour'
                    )
                )
            );
            }
            if ( is_admin() ) {
            add_action( 'customize_register', 'wcmcr_add_colour_picker' );
}
```

Nothing changes in Customizer settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a panel with 
`wcmcr_panel` id.

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( __('wcmcr_panel'), array(
            'priority'       => 1,
            'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
            'theme_supports' => '',
            'title'          => __('Child Theme Settings', 'mytheme'),
            'description'    => __('Child Theme settings', 'mytheme'),
) );
```

The problem was that I referred to the panel in the section but that panel actually did not exist. Hence the section, setting and control could not be created.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Include the customizer.php file directly to the functions.php file.

Comment: Yes, I included using `require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/customizer.php';` , as you can see above.

Comment: And included using `include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/customizer.php' );` .Still no changes

Comment: Panel isn't the parameter of Section. So you need to remove that. And you will get the result. Here are the links of codex you can find the parameter here and also know as well the wordpress customize settings. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_section, (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting) and (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control)

Comment: Actually I have already solved the problem by creating a panel with `wcmcr_panel` id and it worked. As I understand, the section, setting and control were not created because the panel which the section referred to did not exist. Thanks anyway.